# Is it possible to assign HTML button IDs in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I use a for loop to populate a table:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, new { name = "frm", id = "frm" })) {
  <table id="table1" border="1" style ="width:100%">  
    @for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @(i.ToString()+". Details") 
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" onclick="invisiblize(i)">Show detail @i</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
  </table>
```

Is it possible to assign IDs for the buttons generated after the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need to assign the ID's *after* the code runs, but this will allow you to set the ID *while* the code is running...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, new { name = "frm", id = "frm" })) {
      <table id="table1" border="1" style ="width:100%">  
        @for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @(i.ToString()+". Details") 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button id="div@i.ToString()" type="button" onclick="invisiblize(i)">Show detail @i</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
      </table>
```